# java - Why the thread execution was finished before the next line was executed

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a simple algorithm in a new thread.
I wonder why the code that follows waits until the thread is finished in order to run.
Here is a simple program that does the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] strings = new String[10];

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                strings[i] = String.valueOf(i);
                Thread.sleep(10000); // in real code this is wrapped in a simple try catch
            }
        }
    }).run();

    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.print(string);
    }
}
```

The thread sleeps 10 seconds and yet the last iteration was executed after the thread finished running.
I can even extend the sleep time. but the next line (the final iteration) is not executed until the thread finished.
Why is that?

The result is 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Thread.start() and Thread.run()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674174/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not spawning a thread as you just call `run` method directly. You need to call `start`  method instead.

When you call `start` method, JVM spawns a new thread and calls the `run` method of the `Runnable` object. Calling `run` method directly is similar to calling any other normal method, no new thread.

Comment: @rails, in other words:  start() is the method that _you_ call to start the thread, and run() is the method that _the thread_ calls to do whatever it was that you wanted the thread to do.