# how to start new activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to start a new activity called `Counter` when a button is clicked, but I got an error that is the activity is not found...so where is the wrong in my code:

```
t = new Thread(){

            public void run(){

                try{

                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{

                    Intent counter = new Intent("com.example.test.Counter");
                    startActivity(counter);
                }
            }
        };

        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                t.run();
            }
        });
```

this is the manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.Counter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_counter" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: Can you check my answer please ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
   Intent counter = new Intent("com.example.test.Counter");
   startActivity(counter);
```

This is called implicit intent and it needs intent filter

to

```
  Intent counter = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Counter.class);
  startActivity(counter);
```

This is called explicit intent and there is no need for intent filter

You should use explicit intent coz you have

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.Counter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_counter" >
    </activity>
```

Quoting docs

> Explicit intents specify the component to start by name (the
>   fully-qualified class name). **You'll typically use an explicit intent
>   to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name
>   of the activity or service you want to start**. For example, start a new
>   activity in response to a user action or start a service to download a
>   file in the background.

Note: An explicit intent is always delivered to its target, regardless of any intent filters the component declares.

Edit:

You should call `start()` on the thread not `run`

Comment: @user3194430 further reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262816/when-would-you-call-javas-thread-run-instead-of-thread-start

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this

```
                Intent counter = new Intent("com.example.test.Counter");
                startActivity(counter);
```

with this, it would work ..

```
                Intent counter = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Counter.class);
                startActivity(counter);
```

**Or** to let your code work, you are missing     `intent-filter`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.Counter"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_counter" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.COUNTER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You should always provide an `intent-filer` if you want to start an activity with your way ..

Comment: intent filter is no needed

Comment: you can remove the or part not needed

Comment: @AhmedEkri : Your last block of code does correctly show how to use an implicit Intent but two points...First, you should make it clear that defining an intent-filter for use with implicit Intents should only be done if your Activity is to be used by 3rd-party apps. Second, don't derive your Intent actions from `android.intent.action...` - this is not your namespace and you risk confusion if (for example) the Android devs define a `COUNTER` action which bears no relevance to your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

you should have `t.start();`. That is the function that starts a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try running on the UI thread by replacing the contents of your `finally` block with this:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent counter = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Counter.class);
        MyActivity.this.startActivity(counter);
    }
};
```

And as others have said, use `t.start()` instead of `t.run()` as `run()` will block any further action until it completes.